# MySQL One result from two queries in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a little trouble getting my head around this. I have one table of transactions containing both income and expenses and can happily use the following queries to get monthly summaries.

```
SELECT month(`Transaction Date`) as month, ROUND(SUM(`Credit` - `Debit`),2) as revenue 
FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `Account Group` = 'Income' AND `Transaction Date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
GROUP BY month
```

Gives:

| month | revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 50.00 |
| 3 | 400.00 |
| etc | etc |

And

```
 SELECT month(`Transaction Date`) as month, ROUND(SUM(`Credit` - `Debit`),2) as cost 
    FROM `TABLE 1` 
    WHERE `Account Type` = 'cost' AND `Transaction Date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
GROUP BY month
```

Gives:

| month | cost |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 53.00 |
| 2 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 9.99 |
| etc | etc |

I can't figure out a query to combine the data into one result as below. I've used JOINs in the past but this is all in one table.

| month | cost | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 53.00 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 20.00 | 50.00 |
| 3 | 9.99 | 400.00 |
| etc | etc | etc |

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    month(`Transaction Date`) as month
    , ROUND(SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN `Account Group` = 'Income' THEN `Credit` - `Debit`
                   ELSE 0 
                END),2) as revenue 
    , ROUND(SUM(CASE 
                   WHEN `Account Type` = 'cost' THEN `Credit` - `Debit` 
                   ELSE 0 
                END),2) as cost 
FROM `TABLE 1` 
WHERE (`Account Group` = 'Income' OR  `Account Type` = 'cost')
     AND `Transaction Date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation but in better way as follows:

```
SELECT month(`Transaction Date`) as month, 
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN `Account Group` = 'Income' THEN `Credit` - `Debit` END),2) as revenue, 
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN `Account Type` = 'cost' THEN `Credit` - `Debit` END),2) as cost 
FROM `TABLE 1` 
WHERE `Account Group` IN ('Income','cost')
 AND `Transaction Date` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
GROUP BY month
```